# Multiple select statements for mysql search query

Tags: mysql, search, select

can i use select statements for different tables in a single query

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE first_name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
   OR last_name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
```

thats from the table ' users' , i want to do the same search on another table called sellers. sellers have the same fields first_name, last_name

Comment: Combine the two queries with `UNION`.

Comment: Or `UNION ALL` if you don't want to only keep distinct values.

Comment: You can do but why don't you normalize table structure?Why don't save first name and last name in only user table and use foreign key in sellers table?

Comment: Small problem though.. just saw that the two tables are significantly different. but both tables have the first name and the last name fields where i want to run the sql 'like' on and i would like to retrieve the user_id and the seller_ids upon matching .. Help please

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

```
Select column1,column2,column3,column4
From table1,table 2
Where Conditions
```

If you want to do join between tables, check if theirs PK and FK are equals
Eg:

```
Select table1Id,table2Id,column3,column4
From table1 t1,table2 t2
Where t1=t2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search like this
select * from shirts where find_in_set('1','2,3,4,5,1')