# Using search in mysql multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, search

I have two tables users and sellers where user_id and seller_id is different. I want to compare the search query on the first name and the last name of sellers and users and get the results. The two tables have no foreign key associates with it, and on the sellers table its just the seller name. No first name or last name.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE first_name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
OR last_name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
```

that works for the users table.. how to join it with the sellers table?

From the users table I would like to get user_id,first_name,last_name. From the sellers table I would like to get seller_id, seller_name.

Comment: `LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"` just doesn't look right. I guess quotes and double quotes should be swapped.

Comment: Ok. But the query works. its just joining it to get seller details is the problem

Comment: Please refrain from posting the same question twice.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754965/multiple-select-statements-for-mysql-search-query

Comment: Its not the same question.. The earlier one had common fields in the two tables where this one doesnt :)

Comment: Sounds more like an edit to your previous question..

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what you're trying to accomplish, because you don't mention if there's a joinable field like, for example, transaction id, to relate users and sellers.

If you're searching just any users row or sellers row where the subject matches a search string, you might try with

```
SELECT 'users' as origin, CONCATENATE('first_name',' ','last_name') as name
FROM users
WHERE (first_name like '%".$search_string."%' OR  last_name like '%".$search_string."%')

UNION

SELECT 'sellers' as origin, seller_name as name
FROM sellers
WHERE ( seller_name like '%".$search_string."%')
```

keep in mind that, if you remove the 'origin' column, the UNION statement will perform an implicit DISTINCT on the resultset. If you need to display dupe results then you should use UNION ALL.

Comment: Hi . Thanks. is it possible to get the user_id as user_id and the seller_id as seller_id? –